# search throught the html code for an element by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried to search throught the html code for an element named scope using javascript. After that it should show a alertbox with the value of this element.

```
if($('[name=scope]').length > 0){
     var scope = $(this).value();

     alert(scope);
 }
```

But that doesn't work for me. What can i do to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need `val()` instead of `value()`, there is not value function in jQuery

```
var scope = $(this).val();
```

Or simply use this.value, that would be simple and faster

```
var scope = this.value;
```

**Edit** based on comments

```
$('[name=scope]').each(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: oh thats one misktake. But when i corret so code i still get no result

Comment: You need to show related but complete html and javascript/jQuery

Comment: ok, the secound option let the alertbox popup, but the content is undefined

Comment: @dfdsf Try `$('[name=scope]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});` exactly as it is

Comment: @dfdsf Welcome! Glad to help :)